# To find any user from any domain within organization

Tags: c#, active-directory

My organization have many domains.

domainA\user1, domainB\user2, domainC\user3, ...

Recently, I was given this LDAP "ldap.domainA.yyyy.com:1234" and was told that I should be able to look for any user from any domain within my organization.

I tested using codes below and I was only able to look for user from domainA (I am under domainA).

Given my context:

How do I look for any user from any domain within my organization?

Do my AD have to be setup in certain way in order to achieve this? Our AD is setup by our system engineer, I have no knowledge to setup AD.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string currentUser = @"domainA\user1";
            Console.WriteLine(currentUser);
            Console.WriteLine(currentUser.Substring(currentUser.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1));
            string userName = currentUser.Substring(currentUser.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
            string domainPath = "ldap.domainA.yyyy.com:1234";
            using (PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainPath))
            {
                UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext);
                if (userPrincipal != null)
                {
                    userPrincipal.SamAccountName = userName;
                    PrincipalSearcher principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrincipal);
                    foreach (var found in principalSearcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        UserPrincipal userPrincipalFound = found as UserPrincipal;
                        if (userPrincipalFound != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("SamAccountName:" + userPrincipalFound.SamAccountName);
                            Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: " + userPrincipalFound.DisplayName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use this code to look up a user in the domain you're logged into - ive never tried looking it up on one you arent.. other than that - whats the error, whats the problem?

Comment: @BugFinder there is no error, I just want to look for any user from any domain from within my organization.

Comment: You need to run it for each available domain.. Potentially

Comment: Just don't use the `PrincipalContext`, this is really the class for getting the user that is using your app. Use either classes in `System.DirectoryServices` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973834.aspx) or lower level `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` namespace:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alextch/2012/05/07/sample-code-to-query-openldap-directory-via-net-system-directoryservices-protocols/

In case of two-way trust between forests, don't forget to enable referral chasing.